# Is any linear transformation between topological vector spaces of finite dimension a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces

So in the text *Functional Analysis* by Walter Rudin the proposition 1.21 states

> *If $n$ is a positive integer and $Y$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace of a complex topological vector space $X$, then every isomorphism of $C^n$ onto $Y$ is a homeomorphism and $Y$ is a closed set*

So can I argue thorugh the above theorem that any linear map between topological vector spaces of finite dimension is a closed map? In particular is any linear transformation $f$ of $\Bbb C^n$ in $Y$ a closed map? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: See https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuous-maps-that-are-not-closed-or-not-open/

Comment: @RishiSonthalia Okay, but at least is $f$ closed?

Comment: No, only linear injective maps are. Your (standard BTW) example shows that 1-1 is quite needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let be $\pi_1:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R$ the projection onto the first coordinate and so let be $C$ set given by the identity
$$
C:=\Big\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y=\frac 1 x\,\,\,\text{for}\,x>0\Big\}
$$
So $C$ is closed, being the graph of a function,  but however $\pi_1[C]$ is not closed.